# angular 2 AOT compilation

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, angular2-modules

I want to compile my angular 2 projects with AOT.

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

gives this error;

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'null' imported by the module 'AppModule in D:/Git/ng_v4_aot/src/app/app.module.ts'
```

Are there any initial configurations before compiling with AOT?

Comment: Please Share your `app.module.ts` file.

Comment: can you please hare app module as pointed by @Darshita

Answer (score 1):

install
`npm install rollup rollup-plugin-node-resolve rollup-plugin-commonjs rollup-plugin-uglify --save-dev`

1. ng build                            // build with JIT
2. ng build --prod --no-aot            // build with JIT
3. ng build --prod                     // build with AOT

Since @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.28 they've made the AOT compilation the default for production builds.

Create a `tsconfig-aot.json` as descirbed in aot [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

Run the following command:

- "node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json (will build and output ngFactory files)
- ng build --prod